# WordPress login Not Acceptable

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

to start...
I have this error message when I try to login (don't even need to fill anything and click log in, this message appears too)

```
 Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /wp-login.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

but then the page title says 406 Not Acceptable

I have search around and saw some posts with .htaccess and I tried but still can't get it to work.

Ok how this happened was, I was using Chrome and logged in for hours doing my stuffs. But then because of some reason I had to reset password for the original user named admin. So then after password was reset, I tried to login with firefox and the error appeared. At first I thought there's something with admin user so, since my chrome is still logged in (my own login is roled as administrator) I used my login to delete the admin user and created a new one with other name.
Then I tried with firefox again with the new name I created I saw the error. Then I used my own login and same error happened. Then I realized, I don't have to do anything and just by pressing login this error happens.

Now I am afraid to close my Chrome because it's still logged in and working there.

P.S. I tired adding this too

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
   # Turn off mod_security filtering.
   SecFilterEngine Off

   # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

in `.htaccess` where is located same location as wp-config and others

P.S this is getting more confusing for me.  I tried using my phone and co-worker's phone to login into wp-admin and works like nothing ever happened.  But I used both of our desktop to login into wp-admin and both desktop tried firefox and chrome.  Same errors.

Comment: in Firefox, clear cookies for your site.

Comment: I did went to tools>options>privacy and clear recent history and check all cookies history and everything deleted but still having the same problem

Comment: I am having the same issue and I am with HostPapa as well. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

A) It looks to me like it is a webserver/security issue.  What is the webserver you are using.  I am not familiar with that output.

B) Try to put a plain html doc in the same directory wp-config is in and access the file - just for fun to see if it will output (probably will, but maybe not).

C) Check the permissions on the directories and files
see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/directory-and-file-permissions

A stupid thing to do but maybe solve the issue in a hurry is set your permissions all to 777, and see if that fixes your problem. If so, you'll need to see the link about and figure out wordpress's recommend permissions.  I know some directories require write while others do not.

Comment: If that's the issue then I don't think I would be able to run the site at all isn't it? let's say if my site is www.example.com it'll run and works perfectly but if I use www.example.com/wp-admin and I don't need to fill a thing, just by clicking log in will give the error and the webserver using is hostpapa

Comment: www.example.com will point to directory /some/site/dir <br /> whereas <br /> www.example.com/wp-admin will point to directory /some/site/dir/wp-admin,  This two different directories can have different permissions.  Further, there are sub directories within wordpress, those can also have different permissions.  So you can run the site, but only 'parts' are broke.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced the same issue I checked and changed the password database entered in the first installation form in Cpanel. The .htaccess solution described here did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably your server provider has banned the ip of your ISP. Contact the server admin.